# why qthread never quit?

Tags: qt, qthread

```
class A:public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

    public slots:

    void f() {
        while(1) {
            qDebug()<<"f"<<thread()<<thread()->isRunning();
            sleep(1);
            **QMetaObject::invokeMethod(thread(), "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);**
        }
    }

    public slots:

    void g() { qDebug() << "g"; }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QThread th;
    A a;
    a.moveToThread(&th);
    th.start();
    a.f();// running in main thread
    return app.exec();
}
```

the output always is:

f QThread(0xbfdef1e0) true

f QThread(0xbfdef1e0) true

f QThread(0xbfdef1e0) true

I was wondering why qthread never quit, because I do called quit inside the loop using "QMetaObject::invokeMethod(thread(), "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your thread never quits because it's in a tight infinite loop. If you never yield to the Qt even loop, it can't execute any queued actions.  Qt can't magically stop execution of your code in order run the event loop.

If you add the following line to your loop, you'll see that the thread does get stopped:

```
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

because you still have to yield to Qt's event loop in order for it to be able to pass your signal on to the other thread.

Comment: a.f() is  running in main thread not the sub-thread , the sub-thread can handle the event queue.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QThread th;

    A a;

    a.moveToThread(&th);

    th.moveToThread(&th); <------it works ,after I add this line

    th.start();

    a.f();// running in main thread

    return app.exec();

}
```